# Отсортировать соединённые координаты

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuple

Есть список кортежей соединенных координат, например:

```
[((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 4)), ((1, 4), (1, 5))]
```

Как я могу отсортировать координаты, чтобы список не содержал повторений, и сгруппировать соединенные координаты в один кортеж? Количество координат в списке может быть разное:

```
[((0, 0), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 5))]
```

Второй элемент в кортеже должен совпадать с первым, чтобы считаться соединенным:

```
((0, 0), (0, 1))
((0, 1), (0, 2))
((0, 2), (0, 3))

((0, 0), (0, 3))


((1, 3), (1, 4))
((1, 4), (1, 5))

((1, 3), (1, 5))
```

Comment: посмотрите в сторону `set()`

Comment: Какой должен быть результат для списка  [((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 1), (0, 3))] ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy судя по вопросу [((0, 0), (0,3))]

Comment: Я вижу два возможных результата: `[((0, 0), (0, 2))]` или `[((0, 0), (0, 3))]`. Но я не знаю как выбрать. Если использовать высокий слог, автор вопроса отыскивает цепь в графе и заменяет её одним ребром. Что делать если подграф не цепь а дерево или, хуже того, включает циклы?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В последнем примере вопроса именно в этом моменте четко указан ответ как в моем комментарии

Comment: Понял какой ответ, не понял почему. :(

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов можете попробовать так:

```
main_list = ([((0, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 1), (0, 2)), ((0, 2), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 4)), ((1, 4), (1, 5))])


def sorting(test_list: list):
    coords = sorted(test_list)
    res = []
    start = coords[0][0]
    end = coords[0][1]
    for elem in coords:
        if elem[0][0] != start[0]:
            res.append((start, end))
            start = elem[0]
            end = elem[1]

        elif elem[0][0] == start[0] and elem[1][1] > end[1]:
            end = elem[1]

    res.append((start, end))
    return res


print(sorting(main_list))
```

Вывод:

```
[((0, 0), (0, 3)), ((1, 3), (1, 5))]
```